# How to echo random data

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code, that outputs all data from the comment field, however i wish for it to output only two and for them to be random, how can i got about doing this? many thanks.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments  ");

//query the database
echo "<b>Reviews</b> ";
WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
$comment_by = $rows['comment_by'];
$comment= $rows['comment'];

echo "<div style ='font:14px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#cf5c3f            </h>'>$comment_by</h>";
echo "<div style ='font:14px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#ff0000 <h></h>'>$comment<br><br>";

 endwhile;
             ?>
```

Comment: Fix your html first ;p

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM comments
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

LIMIT 2: for two records

and

ORDER BY RAND(): for random comments

See official MySQL documentation:

- `ORDER BY`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html
- `RAND()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html
- `LIMIT`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: This seems to display either 0,1 or 2 comments, I wish for it to always display 2 and for them to be random?

Answer (score 0):

From [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/mathematical-functions.html)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
```